# How to setup and use the snap version UFW in 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, ufw, snap

Checking my UFW version I see its 0.35.  However, I installed the Snap UFW and it is version 0.36pre-16.2.

So how do I use the snap version of UFW?  Do I have to uninstall UFW 0.35 first?

I also uninstalled ufw (0.35) and then ran ufw version and got the following:

```
Could not use iptables. Please run:
  'sudo snap connect ufw:firewall-control ubuntu-core:firewall-control'
```

I tried running that but then got:

```
error: the required argument <snap>:<slot> was not provided.
```

Any ideas?

Here is output of snap interfaces:

[image]

Comment: I ran the first command and it errored.  However I ran the second command without issue.  Then running snap interfaces i see UFW for firewall control so that seemed to work.  However when still running ufw version I get 0.35.  If i uninstall ufw version 0.35 how to get the ufw snap to run?

Comment: I just keep this  link to the related  bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snap/+bug/1594644 . and deleted the answer (it is not complete)

Answer (score 0):

I installed UFW- no previous version was present- on Ubuntu Core 16.04 as below without issues:

```
sudo snap install ufw
```

and `sudo snap interfaces` confirms it's recognized:

```
:firewall-control                    network-manager,ufw,wifi-ap
```

UFW version I'm using:

```
sudo snap list ufw
    Name  Version  Rev  Tracking  Publisher   Notes
    ufw   0.36     296  stable    canonical✓  -
```

It's been a few years since you posted your issue, so maybe you ran into a bug. But as of 20190508 installing UFW installs without issue.